# Javascript regular expression for WebURL

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, url

I want regular expression in javascript that can validate any WebURL.

It should accept below formats:

```
google.com/...
www.google.com/...
http://google.com/...
https://google.com/...
```

I have tried lots of regular expressions for that.But no one is looking perfect.Below are some of the tried regular expressions:-

```
/(http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/
/[a-z]+:\/\/(([a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]+\.)*[a-z][a-z]+|(0x[0-9A-F]+)|[0-9.]+)\/.*/
/(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/
/^(((ht|f){1}((tp|tps):[/][/]){1}))[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#!?&//=]+$/
```

> > I want regular expression should take only 3 WWW.Not more than 3 and not less than 3 WWW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here there are two methods to validate the URL

```
 ^(https?|ftp|file)://.+$

  ^((https?|ftp)://|(www|ftp)\.)[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)+([/?].*)?$
```

Try these...

Comment: The first one doesn't match any URL without a protocol. The second one doesn't match any of his URLs.

Comment: http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/280-how-to-validate-urls-with-regular-expressions/

Comment: Just googling for a regex and posting it does not make it a correct anwser to the question. They still don't match all of the examples. So instead of posting a comment where you have found those not working regex, you should correct your answer.

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about:

```
((http|https|)\://){0,1}([w]{3}.){0,1}[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}
```

Explanation

- `((http|https|)\://){0,1}` for optional protocol (""or "http://" or "https://" will be ok)
- `([w]{3}.){0,1}` for optional `www` string
- `[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+` for domain name
- `[a-zA-Z]{2,3}` for domain suffix like: com, uk, biz, tv, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This one would match all of your URLs:

```
(https?://)?(www\.)?([a-zA-Z0-9_%]*)\b\.[a-z]{2,4}(\.[a-z]{2})?((/[a-zA-Z0-9_%]*)+)?(\.[a-z]*)?
```

Altough it's not possible, to check for exactly three "W" as there might be a subdomain. If you really need this check, I would use a second regex to test that.